# Transform an XML file using an XSLT file on Android

Tags: android, xml, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using FMX in Delphi 11. I need to write a simple app to transform an XML file using an XSLT file.

This code runs fine on Windows:

```
uses xml.XmlIntf, xml.doc;
...  
procedure TForm2.BtnTransformXML(Sender: TObject);
var
  XML : IXMLDocument;
  XSL : IXMLDocument;
  XMLOutput : Widestring;
begin
  XML := LoadXMLData(ReadTextFile(FXML_File));
  XSL := LoadXMLData(ReadTextFile(FXSLT_File));
  XML.DocumentElement.TransformNode(XSL.DocumentElement, XMLOutput);
  Memo1.Text := XMLOutput;
end;
```

But, when I run on Android, I get an error:

> Property or method 'TransformNode' is not supported by DOM Vendor 'Ommi XML'

I wish to try with other vendors, but I don't know how to change it, or maybe change its method to transform the XML file.

Comment: I've found a way to change the venodr with `Xml.xmldom.DefaultDOMVendor:=  xml.adomxmldom.sAdom4XmlVendor;` but anyway, I get the error TransformNode' is not supported by DOM Vendor 'Adom XML'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`TransformNode` documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.TransformNode):

> Note: `TransformNode` is only available when the DOMVendor used to parse this node's XML document is MSXML.

MSXML is only available on Windows.  None of the other `DOMVendor`s that ship with RAD Studio implement `TransformNode()` (I looked at the source code and can verify that).

So, unless you want to try implementing it yourself in your own `DOMVendor`, you will have to find another solution that works on non-Windows platforms.